# AS3 <Key,Value> Collection

Tags: actionscript-3, collections, object

In actionscript object class can act as a collection that stores key,value combinations:

```
var o:Object = new Object();
o["a"] = 1;
```

But when I'm trying to extend it and add some custom functionality:

```
var mo:MyObject = new MyObject();
mo["a"] = 1;
```

I get this:

> ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot
>   create property a on
>   MyObject.

How would I solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the `MyObject` class a [dynamic class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html).

```
package foo.bar {
    public dynamic class MyObject {
    }
}
```

A dynamic class supports the `Object` behavior of `<String,Object>` -- to get the arbitrary `<Object,Object>` map, you need to extend [`Dictionary`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) instead (again, making the class dynamic).

Comment: Great, thanks. A bit unrelated question, but is there a way to get a count of properties (keys) without iterating through the whole object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284947/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-associative-array-in-actionscript-3-0